# External object movement tracking through iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, gyroscope, infrared

We need to **track the external object movement** using the iPhone App;

We achieved this with the help of **gyroscope with accelerometer, and attaching the iPhone with the external object,** but due to some gravitational issues; the app is not tracking the movements as expected.

**Please suggest us for any other alternatives;** and also guide us if we can achieve this using infrared technology.